# Pointer to an array vs normal pointer difference

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *b= malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",b);
    printf("%d",a);
    printf("%d",*b);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, why the pointer to an array doesn't need the address location for scanf compared to a normal pointer?
Also for printf in case of pointer to an array,, why do we have to give the asterisk symbol rather than just the pointer variable?

Comment: `scanf("%d",b);` is broken.  EDIT.  So is `scanf("%d",&a);`.

Comment: This code has undefined behavior on lines 8-11, so it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: There is no array in this code....

Comment: `b` is an array.

Comment: @trojanfoe nope. `int b[10];` : here `b` is an array. `int *b;` here `b` is a pointer, regardless where it points.

Comment: @trojanfoe `scanf("%d",b);` is NOT broken.

Comment: No it's a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's true!

Comment: @trojanfoe stricty spoken there are no dynamically allocated arrays in C. An array has a size : `int b[10];` here `sizeof(b)` is 40 (assuming 32 bit `int`s). `int *b;`: here `sizeof(b)` is always 4 (assuming a 32 bit system), regardless where `b` points to.

Comment: If you wanted to store an array of elements and decide the size at runtime, how would you do it?

Comment: @trojanfoe using `malloc` bit it's still no array, but merely a pointer.

Comment: What is it then?  A pointer?  That doesn't really convey its intent does it.

Comment: @trojanfoe read this: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

Comment: Your code doesnt have any arrays.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've been doing this long enough to know the difference and that `b` isn't technically an array, it's a pointer, but often you will describe a variable by what is does, not by how it's defined.  For example if someone showed us `int i; for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {...}` and asked "what is i"?  Would you say something like "it's the iteration count of the loop" or would you say "it's an int"?  This was all I was trying to convey to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer this, there's a bug in your code that needs to be fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a; // <<< remove * from declaration, such that a is a normal int
    int *b= malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",b);
    printf("%d",a);
    printf("%d",*b);
    return 0;
}
```

So...

> In this code, why the pointer to an array doesn't need the address location for scanf compared to a normal pointer?

In a `scanf` call, the `%d` specifier expects the corresponding argument to have type `int *`, which is the location of the object into which `scanf` is expected to write an integer value.  You *declared* `b` as an `int *`, so the *expression* `b` already has the correct type, and you've set it to point to a valid memory location into which `scanf` may write an integer value.

In the fixed code above, `a` has type `int`, so we must use the *expression* `&a` to obtain an `int *` value.  That value is the *location* of `a`, which is where `scanf` writes the input integer value.

> Also for printf in case of pointer to an array, why do we have to give the asterisk symbol rather than just the pointer variable?

In a `printf` call, the `%d` conversion specifier expects the corresponding argument to have type `int`, which is the integer *value* you want to format and write to the output stream.  We've *declared* `a` as a plain `int`, so the *expression* `a` already has the correct type, and the *value* of the expression is formatted and written to the output stream.

We've declared `b` as `int *`, so it stores an address value, not an integer.  We must *dereference* `b` using the unary `*` operator to obtain the integer value it points to.  The *expression* `*b` has type `int`, and its value is the integer value stored at the location `b` is pointing to.

And, just to be annoyingly pedantic, there's some terminology I want to clear up. 
 `b` doesn't point to an *array* - it points to a single `int` object that just happens to be the first element of an array (or in this case, a dynamically allocated buffer).  A pointer to an *array* looks like this:

```
int a[N];
int (*b)[N] = &a;
```

or

```
int (*b)[N] = malloc( sizeof *b );
```

We're not going to get into that here, because you're not going to be dealing with pointers to arrays that often.

You could rewrite your `scanf` and `printf` calls above as:

```
scanf( "%d", &b[0] ); // note & operator in this case
...
printf( "%d", b[0] );
```

The subscript expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (not bytes!) from that address and dereference the result.

Because of the implicit dereference operation, the *expression* `b[0]` has type `int`, not `int *`, which is why we need the `&` operator in the `scanf` call and *don't* need the `*` operator in the `printf` call.

Answer (score 2):

While `printf` and `scanf` have similar syntax for their format specifiers, they aren't exactly the same.  In particular `%d` for `scanf` expects a `int *` because it need the variables address to write to, while `%d` for `printf` expects an `int` since it just needs a value to print.

The problem with this code is not related to what `a` and `b` point to but how they're being used in the `printf` and `scanf` calls.

Looking at each line:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

This is invalid because the `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects an `int *` but you're passing an `int **`.

```
scanf("%d",b);
```

This is valid as `b` is an `int *`.  It will write an `int` to the first element of the array.

```
printf("%d",a);
```

This is invalid because the `%d` format specifier to `printf` expects an `int` but you're passing an `int *`.

```
printf("%d",*b);
```

This is valid as `*b` is an `int`.  It will print the first element of the array.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Combospirit Do you mean the address the pointer contains, or the value the pointer points to?  For the latter, you already do that with `b`.

Comment: The latter.Do I need to dereference it first and then print? or is there any other way?

Comment: @Combospirit You need to dereference a pointer with `*` to get the value it points to.  If the pointer points to the first element of an array (which `b` does).  You can get an array element with `b[n]` where `n` is the array index, or equivalently `*(b + n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a typo in your code, it only works this way if you use "int a" like this:

```
int a;
int *b= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",b);
printf("%d",a);
printf("%d",*b);
```

In this case it should be clear: scanf always needs a pointer, so you use the & address operator for a and not for b which is already a pointer. For printf you need to dereference the b pointer while a is already an int.

if you insist on using "int *a" you have to write

```
int *a;
int *b= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
scanf("%d",a);
scanf("%d",b);
printf("%d",*a);
printf("%d",*b);
```

and as you see the pointers are treated exacakly the same. However, the *a pointer is undefined (is pointing "nowhere") ans thus likely to crash upon use in scanf.